# Exceeded the maximum number of allowed client connections in ActiveMQ

Tags: java, activemq-classic

I am facing this issue for ActiveMQ Master/Slave config where the client nodes are not able to make connection to Master ActiveMQ node.

In the master ActiveMQ node I am seeing the error as:

```
ERROR | Could not accept connection : org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.ExceededMaximumConnectionsException: Exceeded the maximum number of allowed client connections. See the 'maximumConnections' property on the TCP transport configuration URI in the ActiveMQ configuration file (e.g., activemq.xml) | org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnector | ActiveMQ Transport Server Thread Handler: tcp://0.0.0.0:61616?maximumConnections=1000&wireformat.maxFrameSize=104857600"
```

Where as on the client node, the Jetty process is showing the below message in the logs:

```
Transport (tcp://xxx.xxxx.xxxx.xxxxxxxx:61616) failed, reason:  java.io.IOException: Wire format negotiation timeout: peer did not send his wire format., attempting to automatically reconnect
```

```
Transport (tcp://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxxxxx:61616) failed, reason:  java.net.SocketException: Connection reset, attempting to automatically reconnect
```

Comment: "Wire format negotiation timeout" is not a message from Jetty or it's HttpClient.  Looks like an activemq specific message that occurs after the connection is established and request has been sent.

Comment: But I am seeing the next message as Connection reset, attempting to automatically reconnect

Comment: How is Jetty involved here?

Comment: "attempting to automatically reconnect" is also not a message from Jetty's HttpClient, nor is it a technique that Jetty's HttpClient implements (that's an application specific behavior)

Answer (score 1):

The error message tells you exactly what the problem is:

```
Exceeded the maximum number of allowed client connections. See the 'maximumConnections' property on the TCP transport configuration URI in the ActiveMQ configuration file (e.g., activemq.xml)
```

It even tells you what the connector's configuration is, i.e.:

```
tcp://0.0.0.0:61616?maximumConnections=1000&wireformat.maxFrameSize=104857600
```

Notice that the it's using `maximumConnections=1000`. If you want to allow more connections than `1000` then you should change this configuration.

Comment: But even after changing the maximumConnections=1000 to 2000 its still showing me the message stating the "Exceeded the maximum number of allowed client connections. See the 'maximumConnections' property on the TCP transport configuration URI in the ActiveMQ configuration file (e.g., activemq.xml)"

Comment: Then that indicates `2000` is insufficient for your use-case. How many connections do you expect your client applications to make exactly?